# Master.FindControl giving NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am trying this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Label theLabel = Master.FindControl("HeadingLabel") as Label;
        if (theLabel != null)
        {
            theLabel.Text = "Our Valuable Customers ";
        }
    }
```

i am getting a NullRefernceException error ,i am following a video series ,so i am doing the same ,but not able to run the code.He is is using .Net version =2.0 and i am using 4.0.

here is code for my master page

```
<asp:Label ID="HeadingLabel" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"Text="Online Shopping Website"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: First thing to double-check: is `FindControl` actually returning `null`, or is it the use of the `as` operator? (This is why I prefer casting, in most places... it makes diagnostics simpler.)

Comment: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Find control is not recursive. chances are your HeadingLabel is contained in another control

Comment: Looks like `Master` is null. If so, the page you're on isn't actually based on the master page. Make sure the `aspx` actually has a master page specified in the `@Page` directive.

Comment: thanks @Luaan I forgot to do it on this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `Master` is null. If so, the page you're on isn't actually based on the master page.

Make sure the `aspx` actually has a master page specified in the `@Page` directive.